# How to stop page from redirecting to the previous visited page?

Tags: javascript, database, wordpress, redirect, menu

The issue i have is that when i click on any page in my menu, it loads and then goes back to the previous page i visited. I contacted my hosting provider and they said there must be some code somewhere inside the website or database. But i know for sure i didnt put any code in there. Does anyone know where i could find this code or where the problem could be?

I already tried changing the permalinks and all, but this didnt work.

I expect the page to just normally load into my browser window without redirecting to the previous page.

URL is: http://www.vandeheg.nl/

Comment: You should share more information, like a network traffic trace or something, people can't guess the problem just based on the problem

Comment: If this URL is public you can always share it with people to know more about the error

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see this is a problem with the JavaScript on the site, as with JS disabled I can access all the pages without issue.

I'd recommend trying with all plugins deactivated, and then if that doesn't solve the issue have a look through your theme code for anything like `window.location` that might imply a forced JS redirect.

Comment: Hello, thanks for helping. But when i disabled al the plugins the issue still appeared. Do you know where i can maybe find this window.location? I'm not that advanced/experienced in this, as i am more like the designer of the site.

Comment: Just to rule it out, I'd advise setting the permalinks to something other than plain and see if that fixes it. Have a look at https://yoast.com/change-wordpress-permalink-structure/ if you're not sure how.

Comment: Changing the permalinks also did not work.. But thanks for the tip!